# why i can't change value of a text field by javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, input

I try to get my tag by tag name and change thats value, can you help me to find why this not work?

```js
var r_capacity=document.getElementsByName("capacity");
function expireOtherFildes(){r_capacity.value="";}
```

```html
ID: <input type="text" name="id" class="textBox" onFocus="expireOtherFildes()"/>
capacity: <input type="text" name="capacity" value="xxx"/>
```

Comment: Would you please explain more for the same?

Comment: You just want to change "Capacity" textfiled value, Right?

Comment: Do you have any errors in console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use this:

```
var r_capacity=document.getElementsByName("capacity")[0];
```

`document.getElementsByName("capacity")` returns an `nodeList`.
The nodes can be accessed by index numbers.

```js
var r_capacity=document.getElementsByName("capacity")[0];
function expireOtherFildes(){r_capacity.value="";}
```

```html
ID: <input type="text" name="id" class="textBox" onFocus="expireOtherFildes()"/>
capacity: <input type="text" name="capacity" value="xxx"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

document.getElementsByName returns array. You have access it by index.Refer below -

```js
var r_capacity=document.getElementsByName("capacity");
function expireOtherFildes(){
  
  r_capacity[0].value="";
   

}
```

```html
ID: <input type="text" name="id" class="textBox" onFocus="expireOtherFildes()"/>
capacity: <input type="text" name="capacity" value="xxx"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
var r_capacity = document.getElementsByName("capacity")[0];
```

because `var r_capacity = document.getElementsByName("capacity");` it's returning a **[nodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList)** and you can access that taking use of the `index` which is `0`:

```js
var r_capacity = document.getElementsByName("capacity")[0];
console.log(r_capacity);

function expireOtherFildes() {
  r_capacity.value = "";
}
```

```html
ID:
<input type="text" name="id" class="textBox" onFocus="expireOtherFildes()" />capacity:
<input type="text" name="capacity" value="xxx" />
```

A better approach to do it would be to use [**querySelector()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), this will prevent from getting a problem like you encountered:

```js
   var r_capacity = document.querySelector("input[name='capacity']");
   console.log(r_capacity);

   function expireOtherFildes() {
     r_capacity.value = "";
   }
```

```html
ID:
<input type="text" name="id" class="textBox" onFocus="expireOtherFildes()" />capacity:
<input type="text" name="capacity" value="xxx" />
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByName()` return an array of [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList). You need to select the first index, or simply switch to `document.getElementById()`

```js
var r_capacity=document.getElementsByName("capacity")[0];
                                                  //-^^^
 console.log(r_capacity);
function expireOtherFildes(){r_capacity.value="";}
```

```html
ID: <input type="text" name="id" class="textBox" onFocus="expireOtherFildes()"/>
capacity: <input type="text" name="capacity" value="xxx"/>
```